# How to check if excel has external link in any sheet, using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have about 500 excel sheet to check if it has an external link at all.
By an external link I mean links that can be checked by "excel search tab" → "Links"  and comes up on the Edit Links list.

[image: lINKS]

I am currently trying to use python to replace those links to "" so I don't have to "Enable Content" every time I open any files from my 500 of excel files, but kinda having hard time to detect which file has external links or not.

Could you give me some idea?

Thank you

Comment: External links are kept in the private `_externalLinks` attribute of the Workbook object.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks