# openpyxl - Get the reference a cell in another Excel workbook

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I am working with an excel workbook that contains references to other workbooks, e.g., **example1.xlsx** has cells like:
`=B2 + 'C:path\to\file\[example2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1`

But when I read it with openpyxl:

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

load_workbook(file, data_only=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(self.wb[sheet_name].values)
```

The value of the reference is 1:
`=B2 + '[1]Sheet1'!$B$1`

How can I read these values correctly with openpyxl?

Comment: There is no such method in openpyxl yet, use xlwings.

Comment: Do you have a file you can share? [Xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/) could help

Answer (score 4):

From @Charlie Clark's [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090857/how-to-check-if-excel-has-external-link-in-any-sheet-using-python#comment123934143_70090857) :

> *External links are kept in the private _externalLinks attribute of the Workbook object.*

Which has been renamed to [`_external_links`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html?highlight=_external_links#) since then :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

out = [el.file_link.Target for el in load_workbook("book1.xlsx")._external_links]

print(out) # ['file:///C:\\Users\\Timeless\\Desktop\\tmp\\book2.xlsx']
```

Alternatively, if you want a DataFrame + [xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings) is an option for you, you can use :

```
#pip install xlwings
import xlwings as xw
    
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book("book1.xlsx")
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(wb.sheets["Sheet1"].used_range.formula)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
                                                                0  1
0  = B2 + 'C:\Users\Timeless\Desktop\tmp\[book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1  7
1                                                               5  1
```

Used inputs :

[image]